# Windows の GVim で Medium 幅のフォントを使用したい

Tags: windows, vim

Windows の GVim を利用しています。
例えば 源真ゴシック等幅 の Medium を利用したい場合、

```
set guifont=*
```

として、一覧からフォント名「源真ゴシック」スタイル「中」サイズ「11」と選ぶと、きちんと Medium 幅で表示されます。
このとき guifont には `源真ゴシック等幅_Medium:h11:cSHIFTJIS:qDRAFT` と設定されていました。

ところが、直接この文字列を

```
set guifont=源真ゴシック等幅_Medium:h11:cSHIFTJIS:qDRAFT
```

として設定しても、なぜか Medium にならず、 Regular 幅で表示されます。

どのように設定すれば Medium 幅のフォントを利用できますか？

Comment: こちらに issue として登録しました。 https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/1177

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど、現状バグのようなものと考えておけば良いのですね。

Answer (score 2):

問題の発生していたバージョンは分かりませんが、該当の GitHub リポジトリ上でこの問題が [Issue](https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/1177) として登録された後、[8.1.1224](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f720d0a77e393990b2171a77210565bdc82064f2) のリリースで `:W400` などのようにウェイトを指定できるようになりました。

---

*この投稿は [@KoRoN さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45475/windows-%e3%81%ae-gvim-%e3%81%a7-medium-%e5%b9%85%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment47415_45475) と [@statiolake さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/45475/windows-%e3%81%ae-gvim-%e3%81%a7-medium-%e5%b9%85%e3%81%ae%e3%83%95%e3%82%a9%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment47442_45475) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*